# What C++ design pattern is available for swapping behavior of a function template between production code and testing code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, function-templates

I am refactoring a component to make it more unit testable. A first step is to enable unit testing for some core component code. Unfortunately, this core component code calls some in-component utility functions that directly interact with other components' concrete classes, which are hard to instantiate without the production environment. For the normal utility functions, I can leverage dependency injection to wrap them as virtual functions inside a utility interface and swap in overrides during unit testing. However, there are also utility function templates, which I couldn't apply the same technique, because we can't have virtual function template. Is there a known pattern to handle this?

To give a concrete example, consider the code that follows. Is there a way to switch behavior of the `utilIsNameValid` function template during unit testing? Some constraints apply:

1. I need to directly isolate the logic in `utilIsNameValid` from testing its using code. This prevents me from just switching the behavior of `utilGetName`s with dependency injection, and hope that it would indirectly steer `utilIsNameValid` the way I want it.
2. I cannot change `MyClass`s interface because it is a legacy API with wide impact. @Jarod42's answer is near perfect but requires `MyClass` to become a template, which could lead to callsite adaptation changes.

`mycomponent/util/MyUtil.hpp (in-component utility code)`

```
#include <string>
class TheirClassA;
class TheirClassB;

std::string utilGetName(TheirClassA* a); // a normal utility function

std::string utilGetName(TheirClassB* b); // a normal utility function

template<class T>
bool utilIsNameValid(T obj) {            // a utility function template
    auto name = utilGetName(obj);
    // ... perform the generic name checking ...
}
```

`mycomponent/util/MyUtil.cpp (in-component utility code)`

```
#include "MyUtil.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassA.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassB.hpp"

std::string utilGetName(TheirClassA* a) {
    return std::string{a->getNameInAsWayThatReturnsCharPtr()};
}
std::string utilGetName(TheirClassB* b) {
    return b->getNameInBsWayThatReturnsString();
}
```

`mycomponent/core/MyClass.hpp (core component code)`

```
class TheirClassA;
class TheirClassB;
class MyClass {
    public:
    bool canProcess(TheirClassA* a) const;
    bool canProcess(TheirClassB* b) const;
};
```

`mycomponent/core/MyClass.cpp (core component code)`

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "mycomponent/util/MyUtil.hpp"
bool MyClass::canProcess(TheirClassA* a) const {
    return utilIsNameValid(a) && /* some other conditions for TheirClassA objects*/;
}
bool MyClass::canProcess(TheirClassB* b) const {
    return utilIsNameValid(b) && /* some other conditions for TheirClassB objects*/;
}
```

`production/main.cpp`

```
#include "mycomponent/core/MyClass.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassA.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassB.hpp"
int main (){
    // ... tedious steps to set up TheirClassA and TheirClassB objects ...
    MyClass processor;
    if (processor.canProcess(a)) {
        // ... process a ....
    }
    if (processor.canProcess(b)) {
        // ... process b ....
    }
}
```

`mycomponent/unittest/Test.cpp`

```
#include "mycomponent/core/MyClass.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassA.hpp"
#include "theircomponent/TheirClassB.hpp"
int main (){
    // ... cannot afford instantiating actual objects ...
    TheirClassA* a = nullptr;
    TheirClassB* b = nullptr;

    // ... need someway for utilIsNameValid to simply return 
    //     true or false to test out the rest of the code in
    //     MyClass::canProcess(...) ...
    MyClass processor;
    if (processor.canProcess(a)) {
        // ... process a ....
    }
    if (processor.canProcess(b)) {
        // ... process b ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using some unit testing framework?

Comment: Yes, the example is just a simplified version. In the real code base, we use Google Test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your class template, something like:

```
// myclass.hpp
template <typename Utility>
class MyClassT {
    public:
    bool canProcess(TheirClassA* a) const;
    bool canProcess(TheirClassB* b) const;
};

class UtilityProd; // Class where you have your static methods
using MyClass = MyClassT<UtilityProd>;
```

```
// myclass.inl
template <typename Utility>
bool MyClassT::canProcess(TheirClassA* a) const
{
    return Utility::utilIsNameValid(a) && /* some other conditions for TheirClassA objects*/;
}
template <typename Utility>
bool MyClassT::canProcess(TheirClassB* b) const
{
    return Utility::utilIsNameValid(b) && /* some other conditions for TheirClassB objects*/;
}
```

```
// myclass.cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "MyClass.inl"
#include "UtilityProd.h"


// explicit instantiation to keep separation header/cpp 
template class MyClassT<UtilityProd>;
```

```
// test.cpp
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "MyClass.inl"
#include "UtilityTest.h"

using MyClassTest = class MyClassT<class UtilityTest>;

int main (){
    // ... cannot afford instantiating actual objects ...
    TheirClassA* a = nullptr;
    TheirClassB* b = nullptr;


    MyClassTest processor;

    UtilityTest::setResult(..); // ...

    if (processor.canProcess(a)) {
        // ... process a ....
    }
    if (processor.canProcess(b)) {
        // ... process b ....
    }
}
```

production/main.cpp (and all production case) stay unchanged.

Comment: this is an interesting idea, which does provide a separation and allows the unit test version of the utils to be customized according to each test's need. My major issue with this approach, though, is that it is nearly impossible for me to change the production callsites (e.g., main.cpp) to MyClass given that it is a legacy and widely-impacting API. Let me add that constraint to the question.

Comment: @DXZ its not nice to alter the question substantially after you got an answer that adequately answers the question in its current state.

Comment: @DXZ: I provided way (with `using`) to avoid change to call site (your prod Main should stay unchanged).

Comment: My apology but that constraint is indeed something that I meant to imply but didn't communicate so well in my original post. I do acknowledge @Jarod42 and if there is a way for me to credit him/her, I would be pleased to do so, but not in the form of marking it as the best answer before the question is clarified/finalized through discussion. Otherwise, what is the 'edit' feature of StackOverlow for?

Comment: You should  avoid to edit a question in a way which invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @Jarod42, after a second thought, I think your answer can also handle the constraint for callsites. Before I mark it as the answer, I need to clarify on three things: 1) in your first chunk of code, do you mean `using MyClass = MyClassT<class UtilityProd>;` instead of `using MyClass = MyClass<class UtilityProd>;`? 2) why is the explicit instantiation `template class MyClassT<class UtilityProd>;` needed in the main.cpp? 3) Why separating some code into .in1? If 2) and 3) are not needed, then the callsites have nothing to change.

Comment: 1) I introduced a template named `MyClassT`. and use alias so user might `MyClass` directly (as you use `std::string` instead of `std::basic_string<char>`). 2) explicit instantiation is not in main.cpp, but in myclass.cpp. 3) to separate declaration from definition, regular class use .h/.cpp files, template use .h/.inl . To mimic you regular case, `MyClass` is defined cpp file as before (inl would be a "private" header for myclass.cpp and by test). 2/3 are not needed but should improve compilation time. callsites should stay unchanged with or without 2/3.

Comment: @Jarod42, can you make the following edit before I mark your answer as the solution:
1) Regarding the alias definition in the first chunk of code, change `using MyClass = MyClass<class UtilityProd>` into `using MyClass = MyClassT<UtilityProd>`, if that is the right change. Notice: the right handside is missing a `T` in the template name. 2)  Provide a precise file name in addition to the extension for each chunk of code to avoid confusion.